# Rails 3 serialized attribute validation error: undefined method `read_attribute_for_validation' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When trying to use a serialized attribute (with a defined class) Rails is happy until after the object is saved. I have validations both in my ActiveRecord model and the serialized object (which uses ActiveModel::Validations). As part of my validations, the parent model checks to make sure the serialized object is `valid?`. I believe this is the heart of the issue, but I'm (a) not sure *why* it's causing a problem or (b) the best way to fix it.

I've simplified the problem to a minimal rails project:

### Code

Creating a fresh rails project (version 3.2.6) and creating an `A` model with `rails g model a data:text` I define:

**app/models/a.rb**

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :data
  serialize :data, B

  validate :custom

  def custom
    errors.add :data, "whoopsies!" unless data.valid?
  end
end
```

**app/models/b.rb**

```
class B
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :foo
  validates_presence_of :foo
end
```

**test/unit/a_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class ATest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "weird failure" do
    a = A.new
    b = B.new
    b.foo = 'bar'
    a.data = b

    assert a.valid?
    assert b.valid?
    assert a.save

    assert a.valid? # -> throws exception
  end
end
```

### Exception

Running this test throws the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `read_attribute_for_validation' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/errors.rb:254:in `block in add_on_blank'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/errors.rb:253:in `each'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/errors.rb:253:in `add_on_blank'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:8:in `validate'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_before_7'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__2107971919899649095__validate__2662006763039653414__callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:226:in `run_validations!'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:193:in `valid?'
    /Users/gbelote/tmp/serialize-fail/app/models/a.rb:8:in `custom'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__3204678033069886840__validate__2662006763039653414__callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:226:in `run_validations!'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3204678033069886840__validation__2662006763039653414__callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activemodel-3.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:193:in `valid?'
    /Users/gbelote/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@serialize-fail/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
    /Users/gbelote/tmp/serialize-fail/test/unit/a_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:ATest>'
```

### Another clue

When running `puts a.data.inspect` I get differing results before and after the `a.save`:

```
before: #<B:0x0000010327e710 @foo="bar", @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000010321b7a0 @base=#<B:0x0000010327e710 ...>, @messages={}>>
after:  #<B:0x00000103197158 @foo="bar", @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000001031965f0 @base=nil, @messages={}>>
```

So `@base` within `@errors` is nil, and that's the `nil` referred to in the exception `undefined method`read_attribute_for_validation' for nil:NilClass`.

---

Anyone know what's going on? Is this a Rails bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to ruby 1.9.3-p194 fixed the issue, I was using 1.9.2-p290 previously. Relevant github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6889